# Get the Latest Wordpress Bookmarklet

Tags: wordpress, browser, bookmarklet

Can such thing as a "get the most recent WP release" bookmarklet can be done? I can sure use that link in my browser.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not really a programming question for Stackoverflow. At best, it belongs on the WordPress forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/latest.zip